# can we send an attachment in wso2 for an api as body parameter?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

we are using wso2 API MANAGER 3.0.0, and we have a situation where we want to publish an API whose request body parameter should be an attachment
is it possible to send an attachment in wso2?

Comment: you can upload files in formdata parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new API with the following Swagger file in WSO2 API Manager.

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  description: 'Sample'
  version: 1.0.5
  title: File Upload
host: fileupload.swagger.io
basePath: /v2
paths:
  /upload:
    post:
      summary: upload a file
      description: ''
      consumes:
        - multipart/form-data
      parameters:
        - in: formData
          name: uploadFile
          description: Upload file
          required: true
          type: file
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Valid input
```